# EXC_BAD_ACCESS on accessing NSDate object in a notification

Tags: cocoa, memory-management, nstimer

I have a NSTimer running with scheduled time interval 1.Here I am keep tracking the current Time as given below.

```
- (void)myMethod:(NSTimer*)timer {

NSDate *startDate = [[[NSDate alloc] init] autorelease];
}
```

on some notification I am trying to find the difference between before and after time change.

```
-(void) handleNotification: (NSNotification*) notification
{    
    NSTimeInterval elapsedTimeInterval = [startDate timeIntervalSinceNow];
}
```

Here I am getting `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.

If I use `startDate = [[NSDate date] retain];` no crash,didn't understand where to release `startDate` as I am invalidating this timer on `dealloc`.

Note:can't use properties since need to support 10.4.

Regards,

Akbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to release the previous value and assign the new one.

1 Assign the value like this,

```
if (startDate) [startDate release];
startDate = [[NSDate date] retain];
```

2 Retrieve the value as usual,

```
NSTimeInterval elapsedTimeInterval = [startDate timeIntervalSinceNow];
```

3 *Finally **release** it in* **dealloc** method.

Answer (score 0):

A better way is to not create any NSDate object at all:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject {

     NSTimeInterval _startTime;
} 

@implementation...

- (void) myMethod:(NSTimer*)timer {

     _startTime = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
}

-(void) handleNotification: (NSNotification*) notification {    

    NSTimeInterval elapsedTime = ([NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] - _startTime);
}
```